# Isn't this a bad example for explaining Final in Java?

Tags: java, variables, synchronization, immutability, final

The Java spec [17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) has the following code to illustrate the use of final Fields In The Java Memory Model.
(in comparison to normal fields)

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

The spec goes on to say:

"The class FinalFieldExample has a final int field x and a non-final int field y. 
One thread might execute the method writer and another might execute the method reader. Because the writer method writes f after the object's constructor finishes, the reader method will be guaranteed to see the properly initialized value for f.x: it will read the value 3. 
However, f.y is not final; the reader method is therefore not guaranteed to see the value 4 for it."

**My question is : Isn't this a lame (or at least a badly contrived) example ?**
Or am I missing something here ?

My reasoning to term the example as 'lame' is:

If an object of FinalFieldExample class is to be shared by threads in a multi-threaded scenario, shouldnt it follow the basic tenet of multi-threading, which is to use some form of synchronization. If they had used synchronization, then the issue mentioned would not exist.

The above example seems to advocate Final fields as an alternative (or a partial pacifier) to proper synchronization techniques. In my understanding, final fields have use even when used on top of proper synchronization. And should never be used to gain the advantage mentioned in the example (in the absence of synchronization).

So one could ask:
Isn't there a decent example (with synchronization) to explain the advantage of final fields over normal fields? I guess, Immutability is!

Comment: It's there as an example of what happens with final fields under the current memory model. It's not advocating that you write code like this. see JCIP for advice on how to write concurrent code, where the basic tenet is "use the higher-level constructs (in java.util.concurrent) whenever possible".

Comment: @NathanHughes: Your comment is very interesting. Can you give a reference in JCIP where it advocates that tenet (on using higher-level constructs) ? Thanks !

Comment: try this quote from JCIP, start of chapter 5: "Where practical, delegation is one of the most effective strategies for creating thread-safe classes: just let existing thread-safe classes manage all the state."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing `synchronization` and concurrency.

If a field is a constant then it can be safely shared between multiple `Thread`a without any need for locking.

If a field is a variable then it needs to be `synchronized` or otherwise locked.

You can have a *concurrent* program that has multiple threads reading the same constant field, this doesn't block any `Thread`s.

Any code that uses `synchronized` blocks does so a *huge* cost. This is a very expensive process and should be avoided wherever possible. Not to mention the problems of resource starvation, deadlock, livelock, etc. etc...

If you can use `final` instead of `synchronized` you should do so.

Comment: "If a field is a variable then it needs to be synchronized or otherwise locked." Exactly ! Thats my point as well. Since there is a variable (ie a non-final) in this example, it must have been synchronized. The example seems to be deliberately constructed to allow illegal access to a non-final field and then claims that as a use-case for final fields.

Comment: @vendhan No! This is an example of how the JVM behaves. The JLS isn't a list of use cases it is an description of language specification. This an example of how the behaviour of `final` and non-`final` fields differs.

Comment: Suppose type `Foo` is an immutable class with a final `int` field `bar` loaded from a constructor parameter, `myBar.boz` is a mutable field of type `Foo`, and `myBar.boz.bar` is initially equal to 6.  If one thread does `myBar.boz = new Foo(3);` around the time that another thread reads `myBar.boz.bar`, that other thread might arbitrarily see `3` or `6`.  Were the field not declared `final`, that other thread might see `0` (observing the store to `myBar.boz` before the store to the new object's `bar`).  If one cares whether the value is 3 or 6, one needs synchronization. If one doesn't care...

Comment: ...whether it's 3 or whether it's 6, so long as it's one or the other, making the field `final` will ensure that without requiring any other synchronization.  This is a very nice guarantee to have, given that most types of synchronization would require both threads to cooperate, but with immutable objects the reader thread won't have to synchronize with anything.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: I missed the point in this answer. The issue is not that the value can be changed. See bmorris591's answer instead.**

One of the advantages of immutable objects is that **you don't need synchronization.**

But this example is not about synchronization, it's about the value that the reader thread is guaranteed to see. Even with synchronization, the value of `y`could change, while the value of `x` is always guaranteed to be 3.

Comment: wow ! can you pls tell how the value of y could be misread even with proper synchronization ?

Comment: @vendhan with proper sync no, it could not. Without it certainly could. The point is that although y is a constant is could still be misread because it isn't `final`.

Comment: It's not that it can be misread, it's just that it can be changed by another thread.

Comment: @WilQu I think you're missing the point; the point is that a non `final` field not guaranteed to be _visible_ to the other `Thread` not that some other process can change it. This is actually a very significant point and the reason for the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: @bmorris591 you're right, now that I read the question again I see that I misread it the first time. I guess the question is not final :) Should I edit my answer to say that I was wrong or just delete it?

Answer (score 1):

This spec you refer to just describes how stuff (should) behave. Based on this spec you can decide how to code properly. This example in no way tries to represent a real use case. It just illustrates with a few lines what the behaviour is. And if your jvm implementation does not behave like that, then it is a bug.